# How to allow user to tab through elements with right/left keyboard arrows

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I have a complex react app which I would like the user to be able to navigate through the focusable elements using the keyboard arrows. (Like the tab does)
I have been searching the web for hours to find a solution for this, but all answers solve it for a single component/list/grid, etc'. I want it to work in the entire app which is made of many big and small components. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: You could `addEventListener` to the `document` and invoke a keypress on TAB key there; however not sure how to go about reversing this action..

Comment: When you add keyboard support to say complex widgets like tab, we implement roving tabindex, in which the current focusable element is put tabindex of 0 and others are given tabindex of -1 to not receive focus, then change tabindex accordingly. More info here - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets. Hope that helps!!

Comment: @tarzenchugh I understand the concept but not sure how to implement it. How can i "list" all the elements that can receive focus so I can tab through them back and forth? (with right and left)

Comment: You could use isFocusable util method from [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/examples/js/utils.js) to get the list of focusable elements. 
But I don't understand why you would want to navigate all focusable elements through arrow keys rather than already working using tab keys. It would be against accessibility.

Comment: @tarzenchugh See this link here: It's a Microsoft request.
Microsoft support: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/appendix-b-narrator-keyboard-commands-and-touch-gestures-8bdab3f4-b3e9-4554-7f28-8b15bd37410a

Answer (score 1):

Please note that using the arrow keys wouldn't really help people using assistive technologies. One reason for that is e.g. in a screen reader users often navigate a page using the arrow keys within the so called browse mode. Though one can change from reading mode to focus mode so that the application will handle the arrow keys the authoring practices require an application to be navigable by tab. Also what should happen, if the user hits a grid with the arrow keys? I as blind user would expect that i navigate the grid with the arrow keys instead of being brought to another control. Please see also https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/